# Pattern for passing in a field as a parameter

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented, patterns-and-practices

I'm writing a Rails app which uses ActiveRecord ORM and a Postgres DB. I've got two attributes which are similar but are separate fields in the database. The assignment and saving of these is kinda complicated so I've put that side of things in their own method. The pseudo-code is as follows

```
myObject.attr_a = get_the_stuff_from( ref_one )
myObject.attr_b = get_the_stuff_from( ref_two )

myObject.assign_and_save( attr_a )
myObject.assign_and_save( attr_b )
```

Basically, how can I tell the `assign_and_save` method to distinguish between `attr_a` and `attr_b` so that they get saved into their respective columns in the database. I was thinking of using an additional flag for the method signature, but I think that stunts its re-usability.

What would you recommend?

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you want to do, but does [this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12136262/ruby-get-set-an-objects-property-using-a-string-symbol) help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that you're using Rails, the most common way to achieve what you're trying to do is to use a `before_save` or `before_create` [ActiveRecord callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#updating-an-object).

```
class Model < AR::Base
  before_save :normalize_attributes

  private

  def normalize_attributes
    # Whatever logic you need
  end
end

my_object.attr_a = get_the_stuff_from(ref_one)
my_object.attr_b = get_the_stuff_from(ref_two)
my_object.save
```

Depending on your logic, maybe `get_the_stuff_from` is better located in the model itself, so you might prefer something like:

```
class Model < AR::Base

  def set_attributes(stuff_for_a: nil, stuff_for_b: nil)
    # Something like, depending on your logic:
    self.a ||= get_the_stuff_from(stuff_for_a)
    self.b ||= get_the_stuff_from(stuff_for_b)
  end

  private

  def get_the_stuff_from(ref)
    # Whatever logic you need
  end
end

# Either
my_object.set_attributes(stuff_for_a: ref_one)
my_object.set_attributes(stuff_for_b: ref_two)

# Or
my_object.set_attributes(stuff_for_a: ref_one,
                         stuff_for_b: ref_two)

my_object.save
```

But I don't know enough of your logic to say if the `||=` is enough, but hopefully this will help.

Comment: ...that's an interesting approach; giving the public method a default value then calling its private counterpart with a different signature... I'd love to up-vote this but I don't have the rep.

Comment: That's ok, another way would be to override `attr_a=` and `attr_b=`, but in my experience, sooner or later I'll regret it.  Why is this not solving your problem? If it does you can accept it

Comment: ok, now you have the rep (: